# Convert POJO into JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a POJO.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Emp {
    private String position;
    private String name;
}
```

Suppose, we have created an object

```
Emp emp = new Emp("Manager", "Bob");
```

How can I convert it to a list and save it in a database in JSON format?

The data should be stored in the database in the format below:

```
{
  list:[
    {
       position: Manager
       name: Bob
    }
  ]
}
```

Are there any ready solutions for that?

I  converted an object into a list and then I called the .toString() method on it:

```
Collections.singletonList(emp);
```

But when I store it in the database, the next save goes to the database:

```
[Emp(position=Manager, name=Bob)]
```

But I need to store the record in a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I convert it to a list and save it in a database in JSON
> format?
>
> The data should be stored in the database in the format below:
>
> ```
> {
>   "list": [
>     {
>        "position": "Manager"
>        "name": "Bob"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Since the serialized JSON is required to have a property `"list"` you can't simply serialize the List as is.

Instead, you can define a POJO wrapping this list.

That's how it might look like (I've made it generic in order to make it suitable for serializing any type of list):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class ListWrapper<T> {
    private List<T> list;
}
```

And that's how it can be serialized using Jackson's [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and [`ObjectWriter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html):

```
List<Emp> emps = List.of(new Emp("Manager", "Bob"));
ListWrapper<Emp> listWrapper = new ListWrapper<>(emps);
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        
String json = writer.writeValueAsString(listWrapper);
System.out.println(json);
```

*Output:*

```
{
  "list" : [ {
    "name" : "Manager",
    "position" : "Bob"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to store the object list as JSON in DB then you need Convert the list of object to JSON string using Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Store the converted string to DB.